# How to debug ruby on rails in eclipse aptana plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, eclipse, aptana

I'm trying to figure out this eclipse aptana plugin (coming from a visual studio background). When I try to debug my project as follows:

[image]

It throws this error:

`Unable to find 'rdebug-ide' binary script. May need to install 'ruby-debug-ide' gem, or may need to add your gem executable directory to your PATH (check location via 'gem environment').`

This is `gem environment`:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.5.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 180) [i386-mingw32]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/Ruby192/bin/ruby.exe
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby192/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-mingw32
  - GEM PATHS:
     - C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
     - C:/Users/Lol/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

The server can be started, I can go to localhost:3000 and it loads. But I dont understand this error or how to get debugging started. Any idea what is wrong?

PS. Coming from an asp.net mvc background, I can right click controllers folder and add controller. Then right click an action and generate a view for it. Can I not do this in ruby on rails development?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Issue the following command from the command line:

gem install ruby-debug-ide

The error message is saying that you don't have this gem installed.  It seems as though Aptana does not check to see what gems are installed before activating certain features.

In case you don't know what a gem is, think of it as a plugin that is installed system-wide.

Comment: I had this same issue and running the gem install as salexander has noted will resolve the issue and allow you to properly debug your Ruby code.

Comment: solved mine too, 10x. Note: `sudo gem list` did show the `ruby-debug-ide` but it wasn't enough - used `gem list` to see all installed gem it wasn't there. Installed it without `sudo` and it works.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this [post](http://www.rubytips.org/2011/12/20/installing-ruby-on-windows-7-ruby-1-9-x-guide/) for installing ruby debug for ruby 1.9.3

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem as Mel Padden in osX. With the gem already installed it threw me the same error(I have rvm installed).What I did it was make a symbolic link to aptana and after that invoke it from console.

```
$ ln -s /Applications/Aptana\ Studio\ 3/AptanaStudio3.app/Contents/MacOS/AptanaStudio3 /usr/local/bin/aptana
$ aptana&
```

Is not the best solution, but it works :)

Comment: Not pretty, but for occasional usage this will do for me for now

Answer (score 0):

I'm also having this problem on 64-bit Ubuntu.
Not only can I not debug, now when I open the IDE it gives strange UI errors. The package explorer won't display and dialogs keep popping up.

Here's the listing I get from my Rails install

```
Installing RDoc documentation for ruby-debug-ide-0.4.16...
mel@ubuntu:/usr/share/eclipse/features$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

cgi_multipart_eof_fix (2.5.0)
daemons (1.1.4)
fastthread (1.0.7)
gem_plugin (0.2.3)
linecache (0.46)
mongrel (1.1.5)
rake (0.9.2)
rbx-require-relative (0.0.5)
ruby-debug-base (0.10.4)
ruby-debug-ide (0.4.16)
ruby-mysql (2.9.4)

mel@ubuntu:/usr/share/eclipse/features$ gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.7
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.8
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /var/lib/gems/1.8
     - /home/mel/.gem/ruby/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```