# How to configure aptana for instant running of my script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aptana

I'm working on a Ruby on Rails project and sometimes I need to run a script. Everyone else seems happy running their own server and scripts through the console.
I on the other hand really want to write my code, press a button and have Aptana run my script. For one I hope this will enable breakpoints.

1. How do I make sure it knows the database classes, currently I get TableName unknown name error. "require 'table.rb'" gets me a cannot load file error. Tried adding the file path with / and \, omitting the file extension, using ' or "
2. What is the hotkey for running current file (whatever pressing the play button is)? Or how can this be configured?
3. When I ask Aptana to run a file, I want to automatically save it, how can this be configured?

Edit: I have found the hotkey for running current file is Ctrl + F11, not only is this an uncomfortable combination, it's already in use by Kubuntu and breaks things :(
Also recently Aptana started asking what kind of application I want to run the code as:
1. Ruby Application (always choose this one)
2. Ruby Application (? again...)
3. Test::Unit Test

Clearly I need to change the hotkey hand have it choose Ruby Application at default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you have to change the default hot keys.

1. Answer to your Q1:  You have to config your Aptana IDE to know your Rails project. please refer ror_master's link.
2. Answer to your Q2:  alt + shift + x , then press 1 of the listed options ( t, x, etc)
3. Answer to your Q3:  Your demand is not a good practice, I think. Make sure that you have to MANUALLY save all the files before you do any operations like running a unit test. Please make it as a habit.

Further more, it seems that you are using linux OS like ubuntu? If so, please forget Aptana or other IDEs,  **VIM + console** will satisfy you, and by using these basic tools, you will be more clear of what you are running and the necessary environment knowledge of deploying & running Rails application.

I have 3.5 years of Eclipse and 1 year of Aptana experience, and yes, they are both great IDEs (almost the same), however, about 1 year ago I turn to VIM, which saved my life.

UPDATED:  thanks for the so much bonus scores!  Here are more tips for you:

1. whatever you are using ( Aptana, Eclipse, Netbeans, VIM) , do remember that the HOTKEY is important.

   in Apatana/Eclipse, you should know these keys:

   1. quick open file:  ctrl + shift + r
   2. quick open in recent file: ctrl + e
   3. method outline: ctrl + o
   4. switch : ctrl + F6   ,  ctrl + F7
   5. inspect a method from the statement where it was called: (move the cursor to it then press) F3, or press ctrl key then left click your mouse.
   6. in Apatana for Rails:

      1. ctrl + shift + c : quick jump to controller
      2. ctrl + shift + v : quick jump to view
      3. ctrl + shift + m : quick jump to model
2. VIM has a steep learning curve for us, in my experience, the first 2 weeks is the hardest time. Remember google is your best teacher.  and here are the VIM plugins that I am using:

   1. autocomplpop
   2. fuzzy_file_finder
   3. greplace
   4. mru
   5. nerdcommenter
   6. project
   7. rails
3. this article is worth reading: [Using VIM as a complete ruby on rails IDE](http://biodegradablegeek.com/2007/12/using-vim-as-a-complete-ruby-on-rails-ide/)

Answer (score 0):

To change hotkey:

1. Go to `window` menu (Press alt key if it isn't there)
2. Select `preferences`
3. Select `General` tab
4. Under `General` select `keys`
5. There you'll be able to change keys

Answer (score 0):

For configuration and debugging with rails

I will prefer this lnk [How to debug ruby on rails in eclipse aptana plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104548/how-to-debug-ruby-on-rails-in-eclipse-aptana-plugin)

There are many otgher helps also in the net

http://madcoderspeak.blogspot.com/2008/02/showmethemoney-15-aptana-radrails-hell.html

http://beans.seartipy.com/2008/09/03/setting-up-rails-development-environment-using-aptana-studio/

https://radrails.tenderapp.com/kb/developing-rails-projects-with-radrails/debugging

Answer (score 0):

Just edit the Run Configurator for Firefox, and in the Browser executable area copy the filepath of Chrome, and it runs fine.