# Can't get rails debug to work in aptana 3 in Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, aptana

Before i get into whats wrong, I have tried tutorials and looked at stackoverflow questions, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831260/how-todebugging-rails-3-1-x-appruby-1-9-3-on-aptana-studio3-in-ubuntu), so I don't think this is a duplicate answer.

I am using Aptana 3.0.4, Rails 3.14, and ruby 1.9.2.

I can start the server normally just fine through aptana or the command line. When i try to run in debug mode i get this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsB9c.jpg

However, i have installed the ruby-debug-ide gem, have it listed in my gem file, and bundle installed. I have also tried using ruby-debug19 and ruby-debug-ide19 (bundle installed after trying each gem).

`gem environment` is the correct path to where my gems are installed. ruby-debug-ide and all the others are located in that path.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Please help.

Comment: I just fired up my debugger via Aptana (I'm on the nightly for 3.1). What version of the debug gems do you have? Mine are ruby-debug-ide 0.4.16 and ruby-debug-base 0.11 (running on Ruby 1.9.2-p290).

Comment: craig - here is what is in my gem list: ruby-debug-base19 (0.11.25),
ruby-debug-ide (0.4.16),
ruby-debug-ide19 (0.4.12),
ruby-debug19 (0.11.6),

Comment: I don't have ruby-debug-base and when i try to gem install i get this error: http://i.imgur.com/hyoxD.png

I am also using ruby 1.9.2-p290

Is there anything special i need to do in options or should debug just work with the required gems?

Comment: From googling i think i figured out that ruby-debug-base19 IS the latest version of ruby-debug-base, so i should have had all the proper gems. I think its a path issue? I can run rails s --debugger in console and it works. hmm.