# Ruby:: error to install ruby-debug-ide on windows

Tags: ruby, debugging

I refered this post to install [How to debug ruby on rails in eclipse aptana plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104548/how-to-debug-ruby-on-rails-in-eclipse-aptana-plugin) ruby-debug-ide  and this [link](http://www.rubytips.org/2011/12/20/installing-ruby-on-windows-7-ruby-1-9-x-guide/) .

I have installed

```
C:\Users>gem install ruby-debug-ide --platform=ruby --pre
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed ruby-debug-ide-0.4.17.beta14
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for ruby-debug-ide-0.4.17.beta14...
Installing RDoc documentation for ruby-debug-ide-0.4.17.beta14...
```

But I got this error when I install ruby-debug-ide

```
C:\Users>gem install ruby-debug-ide --platform=ruby
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ruby-debug-ide:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe mkrf_conf.rb
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.16 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.16/ext/gem_make.out
```

Here is my environment

```
C:\Users>gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.11
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2011-10-30 patchlevel 0) [i386-mingw32]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby193/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-mingw32
  - GEM PATHS:
     - C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
     - C:/Users/username/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Something  am I missing ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try

```
gem install ruby-debug-ide --platform=ruby --pre
```

[It should work](http://www.rubytips.org/2011/12/20/installing-ruby-on-windows-7-ruby-1-9-x-guide/).

Comment: Thanks. I think I can debug now.